# RejectedAccessException using readJSON in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We're using a Jenkinsfile with some libraries loaded dynamically using

```
library identifier: "my-lib@$version", retriever: modernSCM(
[$class: 'GitSCMSource',
remote: 'my-repourl',
credentialsId: credentials])
```

in a Jenkins instance managed by other team and with the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin installed.

This Jenkinsfile is hosted in a repository, which also has a JSON file we want to read, like this:

```
{
"foo" : {
    "bar" : {
        "dummy1" : "hjk",
        "dummy2" : "Rio",
        "dummy3" : "qwe"
    }
},
"foo2" : {
    "bar2" : {
        "asd1" : "aa",
        "asd2" : "bb"
    },
    "bar3" : {
        "pepe1" : "aaa",
        "pepe2" : "bbb",
        "pepe3" : "ccc"
    }
}
}
```

So in the Jenkinsfile we load the libraries, we do the checkout of the repo and we call a function stored in that loaded library in which we're saving the returned value from the readJSON step in a env variable.

The problem comes when we try to access some key of that stored env variable:

```
def load(path) {
    env.CONFIGURATION =  readJSON(file: path)
    echo env.CONFIGURATION.foo.bar.dummy1 // ERROR
}
```

we're getting the following error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified field java.lang.String foo
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.unclassifiedField(SandboxInterceptor.java:387)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:371)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:282)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:286)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
at configuration.load(/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TEST/jobs/my-lib/branches/master/builds/65/libs/my-lib/vars/configuration.groovy:7)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:27)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor285.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive
```

We have the feeling that this has something to do with the Jenkins sandbox, which is not allowing to access these fields, but we wanted to know if the issue is this or is other completely different thing, and know if someone has faced the same problem.

Do you have any clues?

Comment: Jenkins thinks that `env.CONFIGURATION` is not a map but `String`. So you got an error that there is no `foo` field in `String` class. Are you sure you are using a right path for `readJSON(file: path)`? Try to print that file before parsing.

Comment: Hi @VitaliiVitrenko, thanks for answering! I found with your answer that if I create a local variable `Map test1 = readJSON` it works properly. So it happens that if I store the `readJSON` return value in that `env` variable it casts to `String` instead of `Map`. Do you know how to store that Map as a global variable (global scope for all the Jenkinsfile to see) without using `env`? As now it's inside a Library.

Comment: If you really want to use a global variable you can initialize it just like any other variable but without type and `def` keyword (for example `GLOBAL_MAP = readJSON(file: path)`) . But this is really bad design and it would be better to return json from the function instead of initializing a global.

Comment: The plan was to use a library function to load common configuration for  all the other functions, like Slack config, NPM config... We tried returning the Map instead of assigning it to the environment variable but the variables initialised in Jenkinsfile are not visible for the libraries, so doing `CONFIG = load("myjson.json")` didn't make CONFIG visible in the library... :(

Have you got some ideas on how to make this kind of "initial configuration" for a Library? An option could be passing this Map to every function call, but...